# Capitalize first word in HTML formatted text

Tags: php, html

I have HTML content of type:

```
<em>this is some</em> dummy text
```

I want to format it to: (Capitalize first letter keeping the HTML tags intact)

```
<em>This is some</em> dummy text
```

using PHP. I don't want to use

```
:div:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

If I try to use `strip_tags` and then use `ucfirst`, it can't keep track of `<em>` tags.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the CSS rule?

Comment: try php's `strtoupper()` function. [tstrtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123: I'm not sure, what is the support for that CSS style. It might not cover all browsers and phones.

Comment: [Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Comment: Its already solved. Please check the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046229/if-there-a-php-function-like-ucfirst-that-will-ignore-html

Comment: Its already solved.


Please check the below link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046229/if-there-a-php-function-like-ucfirst-that-will-ignore-html

Answer (score 1):

```
function capsfirst_sentence($string) {return empty($string) ? '' : preg_replace('/\b(\w)/e', 'strtoupper("$1")', $string);}
```

This is in php If helps you

Answer (score 0):

The ::first-letter selector is used to add a style to the first letter of the specified selector.

Note: The following properties can be used with ::first-letter:

1. font properties
2. color properties
3. background properties
4. margin properties
5. padding properties
6. border properties
7. text-decoration
8. vertical-align (only if float is 'none')
9. `text-transform`
10. line-height
11. float
12. clear

I think without `text-transform` you can not do that.....

so try to do that using this code

```
em {
text-transform:initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet there are better ways to achieve this. But I think this snippet could be of help. It iterates through the string and ignores prefixed tags.

```
<?php
  $str    = "<foo>string</foo> to loop through";
  $strlen = strlen($str);
  $inTag  = false;
  for( $i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++ ) {
    $char = substr( $str, $i, 1 );
    if ($inTag) {
      if (strcmp($char, ">") == 0) {
        $inTag = false;
      }
      continue;
    }

    if (strcmp($char, "<") == 0) {
      $inTag = true;
      continue;
    }

    substr_replace($str, strtoupper($char), $i, 1);
    break;
  }
  echo($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring1 = "<em>this is some</em> dummy text";
$pos1 = stripos($mystring1, '>');
$rest = substr($mystring1, $pos1+1, 1);
$new  = ucfirst($rest);

echo substr_replace($mystring1, $new, $pos1+1, 1);
```

Comment: Include some explanation of your code. Code only answers are deemed to be of low quality.