# Capitalize all text inside of <title> tags for a group of html files in side a single folder

Tags: html, linux, bash, sed, grep

**I'm currently using this code: (Linux Bash)**

```
for x in *.html; do sed -i "a/(sudo grep -o '<title>.*</title>' $x)(sudo grep -o '<title>.*</title>' | sudo sed "s/\b[a-z]/\u&/g")//g" $x; echo moving $x; done
```

and it wont seem to be working, can anyone help me out, do I have to keep using **(sed)** or try using other plugins?

**INTRO:**

I have a like thousand html FILES all of them have  tags inside but the text between the  tags are all lower case,

I want to capitalize first letters for each word between  tags, and do it all at once using loop in bash command.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<title>sample title</title>
```

**TO >>>**

```
<title>Sample Title</title>
```

Comment: 1) what is your error message, if any?
2) could we have sample files?
3) why do you use so many sudo, is there a reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize first word in HTML formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626921/capitalize-first-word-in-html-formatted-text)

Comment: oh, sorry for the sudo i'm running the code inside the /var/www/html/ just wanna make sure it gives permission to edit files, and i'll re write my question for you too. just wait, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following XSLT stylesheet to solve your issue:

**INPUT FILES:**

```
$ more ?.html
::::::::::::::
1.html
::::::::::::::
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title reference 1.html</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
::::::::::::::
2.html
::::::::::::::
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>title reference 2.html</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

**STYLESHEET:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan redirect ">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4" include-content-type="false" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="TitleCase">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="TitleCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="TitleCase">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="TitleCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="TitleCaseWord">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" /><xsl:value-of select="substring($text,2,string-length($text)-1)" />
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='title']">
        <title>
        <xsl:call-template name="TitleCase">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        </title>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CMD:**

```
$ for i in *.html; do java -classpath "./tagsoup-1.2.jar:./saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform --suppressXsltNamespaceCheck:on -x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser -s:1.html -xsl:title_upper.xsl -o:"new_${i}"; done
```

You can download the 2 jars at

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2

and http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ more new_*
::::::::::::::
new_1.html
::::::::::::::
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title xmlns="">Title Reference 1.html</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      The content of the document......

   </body>
</html>
::::::::::::::
new_2.html
::::::::::::::
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <title xmlns="">Title Reference 1.html</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      The content of the document......

   </body>
</html>
```

If you have issue with `saxon` you can just use `xsltproc` as I use a version `1.0` stylesheet:

```
for i in *.html; do xsltproc --html title_upper.xsl ${i} > "new_${i}"; done
```

[image: stylesheet]

[image: command exec]

Comment: great, i'll try this and give you feedback after. God Bless

Comment: wait how do you set it up in ubuntu?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration option http://saxon.sf.net/feature/suppressXsltNamespaceCheck
 at net.sf.saxon.Configuration.setConfigurationProperty(Configuration.java:3727)
 at net.sf.saxon.Transform.doTransform(Transform.java:565)
 at net.sf.saxon.Transform.main(Transform.java:70)
Fatal error during transformation: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration option http://saxon.sf.net/feature/suppressXsltNamespaceCheck

Comment: You really don't need to install Java just to run an XSLT processor; just install a standalone tool like [`xsltproc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xsltproc.1.html)

Comment: @tripleee: I agree with you!!! I have adapted my `XSLT` for a `1.0` and remove all the `upper-case` calls that are available only in `2.0` (version that can not be used with `xsltproc`!

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: are you sure that you have not made any typo? otherwise you can use `xsltproc` but you might have some `<meta>` tag generated by the processor

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: question edited, let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Could not find or load main class net.sf.saxon.Transform -- Maybe i downloaded wrong dependencies the ".jar files"

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: run this command `for i in *.html; do xsltproc --html title_upper.xsl ${i} > "new_${i}"; done`

Comment: ERROR:
cannot parse title_upper.xsl
title_upper.xsl:37: parser error : Premature end of data in tag stylesheet line 2

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: Have you copied the stylesheet file properly? It works for me without any issues

Comment: IT WORKED! , @Allan

I have a final question,

How can i save it to the original one, like overwrite the original not saving a new one

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: you can not do it in one step but you can do it in the following way: `for i in *.html; do xsltproc --html title_upper.xsl "${i}" > "new_${i}" && mv "new_${i}" "${i}"; done` also take some backup of the files before doing this operation, just in case!!!

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguideFrombatangas: does it work as expected? If yes could you validate my answer as correct answer? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Allan this does answer the OPs question, but he should really be guided toward using CSS for the purpose. Just a thought.

Comment: @Timir: You are completely right, this could be done dynamically via CSS/Javascript/php/... but in my understanding of the question he wanted to change directly all the html files on the server level, that's why I proposed this kind of approach

Comment: Server level this is for the SEO so that it looks good in the google search links.  it worked but i noticed something, it destroyed my javascript codes it

it erased some of my dynamically added tags. can we do the "excluded everything between <script> tags"

Comment: @PuertoGaleraguide: could you give me a html sample file?

Comment: i do not know how to send files here but this is the exact thing:

"view-source:http://a-g-o-d-a.info/"